# How to search a string into a string builder in android

Tags: android, stringbuilder

I have a stringbuilder which length is not fixed. 
I have to search a string like "ff d9" into this stingbuilder/
If the stringbuilder contains this sting i can print yes otherwise print not.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("test test test ff d9 test test test");
if(stringBuilder.indexOf("ff d9")<=0){
    Toast.makeText(context,"No",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(context,"Yes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```